# OWIN support for .NETCoreApp

Tags: asp.net-core, owin

Trying to add the Owin package to a new project. In project.json (dependencies segment) red squigly under Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin": "5.2.3". Mouseover displays four errors all relating to support for .NETCoreApp

[image: project.json Owin errors]

Comment: Started working on a new sandbox app and installed the Owin package and it works. This is from the dependencies segment, the same line that threw the exceptions in the screenprint: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.0.0"

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin

Answer (score 0):

You can configure asp.net web api odata | signalr | identity server etc on asp.net core using owin, but you've to use full .net framework. These frameworks are being made availble on .net core, but they're not ready yet. To see a working sample see:https://github.com/ymoradi/OwinAspNetCore